# Función is not a function pero esta definida

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Tengo una web que se divide en la siguiente estructura:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            //Vista
            <div id="VistaPadre">
                <div id="contenedor">
                    <!--boton generado desde vista parcial-->
                    <button type="button" id="OP1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="formula(this)">OPERACION 1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script  type="text/javascript">
                function formula(boton){ 
                    //cosas
                }
            </script>
        </iframe>
    <body>
</html>
```

Esta vista parcial genera en el contenedor un formulario dependiendo del elemento que se pulse en la vista padre, hace una llamada al controlador desde javascript y devuelve el formulario de la vista parcial, lo muestra correctamente y realiza todo el resto de funciones que tengo definidas en el, pero el único elemento que no encuentra es esa función, tengo otros elementos con una estructura muy similar.

Cuando pulso en el botón para que realice su función me sale:

> Uncaught TypeError: formula is not a function

pero me voy a inspeccionar la web y si que está en el script, he probado a:

- Limpiar la cache.
- Ejecutar la web en otro navegador.
- Buscar posibles elementos conflictivos como se indica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169883/10053314).

Dejó de funcionar no se cuando, pero si ha funcionado con anterioridad, he comprobado con códigos anteriores pero no logro encontrar lo que puede estar causando este problema.

**¿Qué puede estar afectando?**

Comment: Has intentado mover el `script` dentro del mismo `div` del boton? aunque no veo que diferencia podria hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que algún elemento causa conflicto con la función, al ser una vista muy extensa (dividida en múltiples vistas parciales con funcionalidades propias), cambiando el nombre de la función a otro vuelve a funcionar correctamente, aun así he buscado por el proyecto alguna función que se llamen igual pero no he encontrado mas que una clase de css.

No se si es la causante del conflicto pero cambiando `formula()` a `pintarFormula()` funciona correctamente.